# Finding the orthogonal basis of a symmetric matrix in c++

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigenvector

I want to find an eigendecomposition of a symmetric matrix, which looks for example like this:

```
0 2 2 0
2 0 0 2
2 0 0 2
0 2 2 0
```

It has a degenerate eigenspace in which you obviously have a certain freedom to chose the eigenvectors. Is there a library for c++ which I can force to find the Orthogonal Basis such that `H = UDU^{T}`?

Currently I'm using the Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver. This gives the "wrong" result as then I have to use `H = UDU^{-1}`. The Matrices will have dimensions of 10000x10000 later on, because of this I want to omit the additional inversion of the matrix.

Does anyone know of such a thing?

Comment: At this point I suggest you to write your own if you know the procedure

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV has support for this. Though, I don't know if you can use it on matrix 10000x10000 within suitable time/accuracy. I believe the best fit in OpenCV is `eigen(...)` method.

There is also BLAS C++ linear algebra library but I am not familiar with it.

Also, there is probably an implemetarion of an algorithm for this problem in the book Numerical Recipes.